# Dynamic ng-init variable - Angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

.coffee

```
@FooCtrl = ->
  $scope.products = Product.query()
```

.html

```
<div ng-repeat='product in products'>
  <div ng-init='images_{{product.id}} = product.images' >
    <div class='slideshow' ng-repeat='pic in images_{{product.id}}'>
       <img ng-src='{{pic.url}}' />
    </div>
</div>
```

I wanna do like this.But `ng-init='images_{{product.id}}'` is throwing some exception.Any remedy or alternate solution for this?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The way you are doing may not work as ng-init take standard Javascript expression so `{{}}` would not work.

Since javascript objects are just a key-value collection. You need to access dynamic properties using `[]` notation instead on `.` notation.

So this

`<div ng-init='images_{{product.id}} = product.images >`

becomes

`<div ng-init='this["images_"+this.product.id] = product.images'>`

See [this](http://jsfiddle.net/cmyworld/jBedr/) fiddle i created

Comment: The newly created variable can't be accessible in angular controller. $scope.images_x is undefined. any solution???

Comment: @Chandermani it somehow worked. But how? Why this works and where from did you get the knowledge, that this solution will fit?  Browsing through Angular docs I saw that it frequently lacks thorough explanations for some problems - examples are too easy; there are too less more advanced examples.  Does it mean, I'm forced to browse through Angular source code to come by myself with such solution, you provided?

Comment: This is not a common use case. Expressions in Angular are evaluated in context of scope. And it seems `this` during expression evaluation points to the scope object. Rest is our understanding of JavaScript which we use to access dynamic variable using `[]`. It was more of hit and trial and a thought around what would `this` point to when evaluation happen. I did not look at source code.