# why does my ng-init not working

Tags: html, angularjs

```
<body ng-init="user=${userID};month=${month};curPageNum=${currentPage}">
```

I wrote this by JSP,and i initial the value in the body tag,
but in the controller,i wrote:

```
console.debug($scope.user  + " "+$scope.month}
```

but only $scope.month have the value,$scope.user displays undefined,
and after some tries, i found that if the value contains letters，it just display undefine,only the pure number can work.

I don't know why this happen,so can you help me to solve this?Thank you very much

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your initialisation of the variables does not wrap the values in strings they are failing to assign. the JS is reading it as `user=mary;` i.e. assign the variable `mary` to `user`. That's why numbers work. Try this :

```
<body ng-init="user='${userID}';month=${month};curPageNum=${currentPage}">
```

Answer (score 0):

You can refer [Dynamic ng-init variable - Angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18031560/dynamic-ng-init-variable-angularjs)

Also, You can refer [http://www.w3schools.com/angular/angular_directives.asp](http://Ng-Init%20example)

you can initialise value as below

```
<body ng-init="user='${userID}';month='${month}';curPageNum='${currentPage}'">
```